# Calling procedure with parameters into event in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, events, stored-procedures

How can I call this procedure with this parameter?

```
SET @newday = current_date() + INTERVAL 6 DAY;
CALL add_day('20','@newday')
```

I can't save it because it gives me some syntax errors and I can't find it!

Comment: I'm quite sure it does not only give *some* syntax error...

Comment: what else ??? I know, but you can understand what I'm trying to do

Comment: If it gives a syntax error then add it to the question.

Comment: Could you show us the whole exception, you got? And probably the definition of the `add_day` procedure.

Comment: @pozs MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL add_day('20',@newday)' at line 2

Comment: And, the `add_day` procedure?

Comment: @pozs ` `CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_day`(IN `d_id` INT, IN `dates` VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
      DECLARE x  INT;
      SET @x = 1;
      SET @doc_id = d_id;
      SET @d = dates; 
      
      WHILE @x  <= 30 DO
          INSERT INTO  `e-heal`.`scheduler`
              (`scheduler_id` ,`d_id` ,`hour_id` ,`date` ,`available`)
              VALUES (NULL ,  @doc_id,  @x,  @d,  '0');
          SET  @x = @x + 1; 
      END WHILE;
END` `

Comment: it works for me - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edc1d/1

Comment: @pozs :( I send you the error! I don't know why

Comment: did you run this in php with `mysql_query()`? it does not supports to run multiple queries. (and it will be deprecated in php 5.5)

Comment: @pozs I tested my procedure many times. It's working great. the problem is when I'm putting this: `SET @newday = current_date() + INTERVAL 6 DAY;` before call the procedure into the event. When I'm calling the procedure with phpmyadmin sql with my parameters, for example: CALL add_day('20','2013-05-01')
it's working and adding the records into the database.
But when I try to get the next week with `current_date()` to put automatically the date for next into the procedure, I'm getting this error!

Comment: @pozs thank you so much!! I found the answer

Answer (score 0):

You said it is a function. If it is a function you should use `SELECT` instead of `CALL`.

If it's a procedure, you are invoking it correctly. In that case, the error is in the body of the procedure, not in the call.

Comment: The procedure working great. I test it many times.

Comment: There is no syntax error in the way you call it. Probably, it gives error with certain input values...

Answer (score -1):

Follow what I did and work it.

Function I created:

```
create function add_day(days int, date_from datetime)
returns datetime 
return date_add(date_from, interval days day);
```

Call I made:

```
SET @newday1 = current_date() + INTERVAL 6 DAY;
select add_day('20',@newday1);
```

If you are having an error when run the script above, then the error can be inside the function. I change the way you are invoking the function because you told us is a function and not a proc.

Comment: Yes i have the function.. But it gives me again syntax error

Comment: I did this before.. it gives me the date **2013-04-30**

Comment: SET @var_name = 'value' is correct. No need to use :=

Comment: @Federico Ok, but how can I fix the basic problem?

Comment: Sorry @MoonFox. I answered your question but maybe I did not understand it. What is your real problem? Where are you getting syntax error? Are trying to encapsulate the code below inside a function?

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin and I can't save the event because gives me syntax error: _MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL add_day('20',@newday)' at line 2_

Comment: Could you post all the command are you running to create the event? I do not use phpadmin. I use workbench but I will try to reproduce your issue and help you.

Comment: @JoseAreas Here: `SET @newday= current_date() + INTERVAL 6 DAY;
CALL add_day('20',@newday);`

Comment: @MoonFox, I changed my answer with some steps I did. It should be very interesting to us if you post here the function script. Maybe you are getting error inside the script.

Comment: @JoseAreas I tested my procedure many times. It's working great. the problem is when I'm putting this: `SET @newday = current_date() + INTERVAL 6 DAY;` before call the procedure into the event. When I'm calling the procedure with phpmyadmin sql with my parameters, for example: CALL add_day('20','2013-05-01')
it's working and adding the records into the database.
But when I try to get the next week with `current_date()` to put automatically the date for next into the procedure, I'm getting this error!

Comment: @JoseAreas thank you so much!! I found the answer

Comment: @MoonFox, Tell it to us. We are curious.

Comment: @JoseAreas I put this: `SET @newday= current_date() + INTERVAL 6 DAY;` into the procedure, and I'm calling the event with only one parameter!

Comment: If it works for you, then it is great.